# Drop down menu tabs on mobile showing content in one tab only

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Good day all & thanks for your attention. I have drop down menu with tabs, its working fine on desktop, but on mobile in one "active" tab showing content only. while clicking on "register tab" still content is showing from  active tab. i have tried to apply css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.tab-content > .tab-pane{display: block;}}
```

by this both content extracting in active tab.
How to make active both tabs on mobile? Thank you very much!

Bellow is code for form.

```
  <div class="dropdown messages-menu">
  
  <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="tmarketst"><i  class="porto-icon-user-2" ></i></span>  My Profile
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Log in </a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
      
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><?php echo do_shortcode("[wc_login_form_mmy]"); ?> </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"><?php echo do_shortcode("[wc_reg_form_mmy]"); ?></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-menu ul{transition-duration: .25s;
  
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  background-color: none;}
  

.dropdown-menu > ul > li {font-size:15px;
} 
@media (max-width: 459px) {
    .dropdown-menu > ul > li {font-size:10px;  
}}

.dropdown-menu ul:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  transform: translateY(70%);
}
.tabs > li.active {
  color: #4D4D4D;
}
.dropdown-menu ul.active:before {
  transition-duration: .5s;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.tab-content{font-size:14px;}
@media (max-width: 459px) {
.tab-content{font-size:10px;}}
.dropdown-menu:hover {display: inline-block}
```

Comment: insert full css

Comment: Added. But even removing all css that is not helps.